# Training a catboost model in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse, catboost, catboostregressor

So far as I see in [docs](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/guides/apply-catboost-model/). There is an only option to use pretrained CatBoost models in ClickHouse. However are there any work arounds to train CatBoost models directly in ClickHouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, you can only prepare data for training in ClickHouse, but you'll have to run it externally.